# SQLite How to Group data according to custom rules

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, count, window-functions

I have a table as below.
If I do a group by operation on the name field, the key of b is 11,but what I need to leave is 12, because 12 has already appeared in other records.
What should I do to achieve this result, without using the max aggregation method

Introduce the meaning of the table,
key-12 also provides name-a, name-b, key-11 only provides name-b
For name-c, there are three key that can provide name-c, all of which are not repeated

```
|name|key|
| a | 12 |
| b | 11 |
| b | 12 |
| c | 15 |
| c | 14 |
| c | 17 |
....
```

What I hope is that the result obtained through group by is:

```
|name|key |
| a  | 12 |
| b  | 12 |
| c  | 15 |
```

To perform group by operations through the name field,
b needs to leave key-12, because key-12 provides both name-a and name-b,
so key-11 is not needed.

For name-c, there are three key that can provide name-c, all of which are not repeated, so let's just use the one that appears for the first time.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: You need to explain the logic by which we know that key `12` belongs to `name = a`, and not to `name = b`.

Comment: I added a description in the question, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `key` is unique for each `name` you can use `COUNT()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` window functions:

```
select name, key
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by name order by counter desc, rowid) rn
  from (
    select *, rowid, count(*) over (partition by key) counter
    from tablename
  )
) 
where rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=487fd66daf8897b5c25767d0464a272e).
Results:

```
> name | key
> :--- | --:
> a    |  12
> b    |  12
> c    |  15
```

Comment: Very cool and thank you very much, but it may not solve my problem. Sql found that I used sorting for key. In fact, I don't want to sort for this key. It's just a logo. I want to judge whether he appears in other records to determine whether to use this record directly or the record generated by the original group by rule.

Comment: @tomtao This code does not sort by key. It counts how many times a key appears in the table to decide which key will be returned for each name. Finally the key that appears most is the one that you get for each name.

Comment: @foroas I may not quite understand your code, but also need to improve the corresponding skills, and maybe I did not express the problem clearly, your code can not solve my problem for the time being, thank you very much. I consider redescribing the problem. Thank you.

Comment: My code solves your problem as you described it. If you have a different requirement then ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will redescribe the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, I have modified the description of the problem. Could you please help me to see if my request is possible? Thank you.

Comment: @tomtao *the one that appears for the first time* is not guaranteed. Tables are unordered sets. I use `rowid` to define the order, but even this `rowid` may be reused by SQLite. If there is some other column like a primary key that defines the order then you should use that.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for your help. I'll continue to see if there are other solutions that are not in the sql layer.